# Material-UI DataGrid: Removing a row from state causes Cannot read property error

Tags: datagrid, material-ui

1. I have a material UI Datagrid as follow:

```
<DataGrid
                            className={classes.datagrid}
                            page={page}
                            pageSize={rowsPerPage}
                            rows={rows}
                            columns={columns}
                            sortModel={sortModel}
                            rowCount={meta.total}
                            loading={store.panels.loading}
                            rowsPerPageOptions={
                                [5, 10, 25, 50] as PageSizeOptions[]
                            }
                            disableSelectionOnClick
                            onPageSizeChange={changePageSize}
                            autoHeight
                            onPageChange={handlePageChange}
                            onSortModelChange={updateSort}
                            components={{
                                loadingOverlay: LoadingOverlay,
                                noRowsOverlay: NoRowOverlay,
                            }}
                        />
```

2. I have an observable mobx array. const rows = [inherited mobx array from global store]
3. I then delete a row from the array on the global store.
4. I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
(anonymous function)
node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid/dist/index-esm.js:15
etc...
```

The mobx array is an array of objects [ { id: 1, name: "bob" }, etc... ]

The columns:

```
const columns: ColDef[] = [
        { field: 'id', hide: true },
        {
            headerName: 'Name',
            field: 'name',
            width: 110,
        },
    ];
```

This error only occurs when I try to remove a row.
Adding, fetching or updating works fine.

It seems to be a bug with MUI DataGrid
https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rows/

Let me know.

Regards,
Emir

Comment: Having the same issue using useFieldArray from react-hook-form library. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was released in v4.0.0-alpha.10.
Reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/571

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed bug with DataGrid. You need to downgrade library to version: 4.0.0-alpha.8 or set it to "https://pkg.csb.dev/mui-org/material-ui-x/commit/02423225/@material-ui/data-grid"

Comment: I have been dealing with this ALL day. It is very refreshing for me to see you say it is a bug. However, how do you KNOW it's a bug. Can you provide a link to an issue on their GutHub page?

Comment: Additionally, downgrading the library to 4.0.0-alpha.8 still does not fix the issue for me.

Comment: I just filed this bug report: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/607

Is there another?

Comment: here you go: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/571